# PHP validation - check if 1 of 3 fields is populated

Tags: php, validation

I'm trying to validate 3 fields that are related. These 3 fields are in a form that has a couple dozen fields already, many of which are being validated.

For the 3 related fields in question, I need to write code that checks if 1 of any of the 3 are populated, and then throws an error if any of the other 2 are not.

- So if A is populated and B and C are not = error.
- If B is populated and A and C are not = error.
- if C is populated and A and B are not = error.

  And then so on with two being populated and the third, not.

Like: if A and B are populated and C is not = error.

Here's where I started, but not sure if this is correct validation:

```
if(!empty($post['email_notify_subject']) 

    && empty($post['email_notify_date']) 
    && empty($post['email_notify_emails']))

{

$errors['email_notify_date'] = 'Enter Notify Date'; 
$errors['email_notify_emails'] = 'Enter Notify Emails';

} 

else if (empty($post['email_notify_subject']) 

    && !empty($post['email_notify_date']) 
    && empty($post['email_notify_emails'])) 

{

$errors['email_notify_subject'] = 'Enter Notify Subject';
$errors['email_notify_emails'] = 'Enter Notify Emails';

} 

else if (empty($post['email_notify_subject']) 

    && empty($post['email_notify_date']) 
    && !empty($post['email_notify_emails'])) 

{

$errors['email_notify_subject'] = 'Enter Notify Subject';
$errors['email_notify_date'] = 'Enter Notify Date';

}
```

Comment: We need more code than one line...

Comment: Post the html code for those fields as well as your <form> line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is this?

```
if (
    (
        ! empty($post['email_notify_subject']) &&
        empty($post['email_notify_date']) &&
        empty($post['email_notify_emails'])
    ) ||
    (
        empty($post['email_notify_subject']) &&
        ! empty($post['email_notify_date']) &&
        empty($post['email_notify_emails'])
    ) ||
    (
        empty($post['email_notify_subject']) &&
        empty($post['email_notify_date']) &&
        ! empty($post['email_notify_emails'])
    )
) {
    // only 1 field filled out
}
```

Or here's another way:

```
$num_filled_out = 0;
if ( ! empty($post['email_notify_subject']) ) $num_filled_out++;
if ( ! empty($post['email_notify_date']) ) $num_filled_out++;
if ( ! empty($post['email_notify_emails']) $num_filled_out++;
if ($num_filled_out <= 1) {
    // 1 or 0 filled out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Tested this , but give it a try:

```
<?php
  if(empty(array(
    $_post['email_notify_subject'],
    $_post['email_notify_date'],
    $_post['email_notify_emails']))){
      echo "All Three filed required"; //or other instructions
}
  else{
   //Proceed with the form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a better approach because you can have all your fields you want to check and all the according error messages in one array. Also it's more scalable.

Note that you have to test if your form `method` attribute is set to `post` and you have given the right names to your input fields.

```
$data_to_check = array(
    'email_notify_subject'=>array(
        'error'=>'Enter Notify Subject'
    ),
    'email_notify_date'=>array(
        'error'=>'Enter Notify Date'
    ),
    'email_notify_emails'=>array(
        'error'=>'Enter Notify Emails'
    ),
);

$errors = array();

foreach($data_to_check as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($post[$key])) {
        $errors[] = $value['error'];
    }
}

if (!empty($errors)) {
    foreach($errors as $key => $value) {
        echo '<p class="error">'.$value.'</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about errors at the end, see the following as reference:

```
$post['email_notify_subject']   = array();  // same (== not ===) as null
$post['email_notify_date']      = null;     // same (== not ===) as empty array
$post['email_notify_emails']    = 'test string';

$errors['email_notify_subject']   = 'Enter Notify Subject';
$errors['email_notify_date']      = 'Enter Notify Date';
$errors['email_notify_emails']    = 'Enter Notify Emails';

foreach ($post as $key => $data) {

    if (!empty($data)) {

        unset($errors[$key]); // if $post data not empty, unset error msg
    }
}

var_dump($errors); // test dump $errors
```